# Out Of Memory Exception when finding combinations of List of string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a 2D array of strings.
What I want to do is get the combination of first column with second, the result of this with third and so on.
Example:

Suppose my 2D array is

```
a c x
b d y
null null z
```

I should get a result of `IEnumerable<string>` as below,

```
{a`c`x, a`c`y, a`c`z, a`d`x, a`d`y, a`d`z, b`c`x, b`c`y, b`c`z, b`d`x, b`d`y, b`d`z}
```

The count of the resulting `IEnumerable<string>` might go to 10^10

I am trying to achieve this by following code

```
List<string> firstColumnOrResult = new List<string>();
List<string> nextColumn = new List<string>();
firstColumnOrResult = Enumerable.Range(0, trueSetMatrix.GetLength(0)).Select(x => trueSetMatrix[x, 0]).ToList();
for(int i=1;i<trueSetMatrix.GetLength(1);i++)
{
    nextColumn = Enumerable.Range(0, trueSetMatrix.GetLength(0)).Select(x => trueSetMatrix[x, i]).ToList();
    firstColumnOrResult = firstColumnOrResult.SelectMany(x => nextColumn, (y, z) => y + " ` " + z).ToList();
}
```

where `trueSetMatrix` is my 2D array.

So my code here throws an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Is there a alternate way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use Linq for that. Write a function that contains 2 nested for loops, and generates IEnumerable<string> with yield return.

Comment: @Soonts I think it woul look cleaner and easier to grasp, but would that really help with the out-of-memory exception, if in the end `.ToList()` is called on it?

Comment: @nvoigt The OP's limit is 10^10 strings, making a list or array of that size is guaranteed to OOM. But they wrote they need IEnumerable not List. Unlike lists, generators don't consume memory per element, they can even return infinitely long sequences.

Comment: @Soonts I assumed the OP knew that and having it materialized was a requirement. But you are right, that was my assumption and maybe that's wrong. You should make that an answer.

Comment: @Soonts thanks for your suggestion but I'm not really sure would I get all the combinations from 2 nested loops. Can u please post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a complete code. It’s much more complicated than your naïve version, but it should work even when the output sequence has 10^10 values. If you call `ToArray()` or `ToList()` on the result of the `generateCombinations()`, you’ll likely crash with the same out of memory exception. Instead, consume values as they are generated, using `foreach` or linq.

```
static IEnumerable<string> generateCombinations( string[,] data )
{
    int rows = data.GetLength( 0 );
    int cols = data.GetLength( 1 );
    if( rows <= 0 || cols <= 0 )
        yield break;
    // Reshape data into array of arrays, 1 array per column, skipping nulls at the same time.
    // It's faster to skip nulls in advance, before running the main loop.
    string[][] columns = new string[ cols ][];
    for( int c = 0; c < cols; c++ )
    {
        string[] column = Enumerable.Range( 0, rows )
            .Select( r => data[ r, c ] )
            .Where( str => null != str )
            .ToArray();
        // Ensure the column has at least a single non-null value, return otherwise.
        if( column.Length <= 0 )
            yield break;
        columns[ c ] = column;
    }

    // Iterator state, i.e. row indices. C# initializes arrays with zeros.
    int[] indices = new int[ cols ];
    // Another optimization here: reusing string builder across iterations.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // Run the main loop.
    while( true )
    {
        // Generate value at the current iterator state
        sb.Clear();
        for( int c = 0; c < cols; c++ )
        {
            if( c > 0 )
                sb.Append( '`' );
            sb.Append( columns[ c ][ indices[ c ] ] );
        }
        yield return sb.ToString();

        // Advance to the next value
        for( int c = cols - 1; true; c-- )
        {
            int i = indices[ c ];
            i++;
            if( i < columns[ c ].Length )
            {
                // Still have one more value in that column
                indices[ c ] = i;
                break;
            }

            // No more values in that column.
            if( c > 0 )
            {
                // Reset current index to 0, and continue left to the next column
                indices[ c ] = 0;
                continue;
            }
            // Finished - exit the function
            yield break;
        }
    }
}

static void Main( string[] args )
{
    string[,] data = new string[ 3, 3 ]
    {
        { "a", "c", "x" },
        { "b", "d", "y" },
        { null, null, "z" },
    };

    foreach( string c in generateCombinations( data ) )
        Console.WriteLine( c );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not a lot you can do if your result set is larger than your memory.

You can try to minimize the memory footprint of a single result, you can filter your result set if you aren't actually interested in all the results, you can upgrade your memory so it can store more values or you can write your results to something that is not the memory, for example a file or a database.

But if your result set really has to be that large, then I guess you will not be able to use your memory for storage. Look into files or databases.